# Find eigenvalues given equations with independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

For a 4x4 matrix A, Suppose there exists four independent vectors $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $x_4$, such that $$(A-aI)x_1=0, (A-aI)x_2=x_1,(A-aI)x_3=x_2,(A-bI)x_4=0.$$
Find the eigenvalues of A, where a and b are constants.

By equation 1 and 4, I know that a and b are two eigenvalues of A.
By replacing variables into the first equation, I get $(A-aI)^2x_2=0$ and $(A-aI)^3x_3=0$.
Does it imply that the third and the fourth eigenvalue are also a and a? If so, how?

Comment: Look up the Jordan form of a matrix where, for some eigenvalue, the dimension of the eigenspace is less than the multiplicity of the eigenvalue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand, could you please elaborate? Do you think the eigenvalues are a, a, a, b?

Comment: Let $f:\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^4$ be the linear map whose matrix in the canonical basis is $A.$ What is its matrix in the basis $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$? And what are the eigenvalues of a triangular matrix?

Comment: I don't understand your first question, sorry. For the second question, the eigenvalues are the entries on the diagonal. But how does it relate to the question?